# Common silverlight object for all web pages

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

In my web project I want to have global silverlight control (music player) common for all web pages in my project. When user click in hyperlink(want change view in web app) I dont want refresh all view with silverlight control but only part of view. Some think like in [grooveshark.com](http://grooveshark.com). I think that for all views in my project I use PartialViews and load them using ajax(its good idea? Maybe anyone have better idea?) but I have problem. If we call action not from ajax but we write adress in web browser I get only partial view without shared layout. Also after load partial view with ajax and after them click back in browser I have updated adress in browser but not updated view(view not render).

Most important for me it's to have global silverlight object for all pages in my project and during the change view don't reload silverlight control.

Any ideas how do this?